# how to get a string after certain appearance of the string separator?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

for example I have this xml:

```
<ns5:folio><ns5:portfolioName ns5:portfolioNameScheme="test">ROOT:B1:B2:B3:B4:B5:B6</ns5:portfolioName></ns5:folio>
```

And I want the xslt to find the string after the 4th : and before the 5th :
which is B4.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Good question, +1. In addition to the good answer by @LarsH, see my answer for an easy XSLT 1.0 solution that is flexible and applicable for any number of delimited string components uses the power of FXSL to make difficult tasks easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Besides the good answer by @LarsH (+1), if you are stuck with XSLT 1.0, you can use the `str-split-to-words` function/template of [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
   <xsl:import href="strSplit-to-Words.xsl"/>

   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="vwordNodes">
        <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-words">
          <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="/"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters" 
                          select="':'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:value-of select="ext:node-set($vwordNodes)/*[5]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document (with added namespace definition to make it well-formed):**

```
<ns5:folio xmlns:ns5="unknown!!!" >
    <ns5:portfolioName ns5:portfolioNameScheme="test">ROOT:B1:B2:B3:B4:B5:B6</ns5:portfolioName>
</ns5:folio>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
B4
```

**Do note**: This solution is very easy to use (just change `[5]` to `[1000]`) in case we need to retrieve the 1000-th component in the colon-separated string.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `substring-before` and `substring-after`.

```
<xsl:variable name="x">ROOT:B1:B2:B3:B4:B5:B6</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after($x, ':'), ':'), ':'), ':'), ':')"/>
```

Comment: Do you seriously recommend *this*? Your hard drive might not have enough space to write/save the XSLT code if we need the Nth component -- for a suitable value of N :)  :)

Comment: @Dimitre, It depends. If N = 4, why not?

Comment: Actually, @Kirill, it is good to have answers as this, because an **ugly solution** helps more clearly see the beauty of a better one.

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT/XPath 2.0, you can use `tokenize()`:

```
tokenize($x, ':')[5]
```

Comment: thanks mate. but I don't have xslt 2.0 . I am still on xslt 1.0 actually might be stupid question but how can I get xslt 2.0? Do I need to install anything?